# How are the network shards allotted to miners?

Tags: bitcoin, network, sharding

Are they allotted randomly?

And, is there an upper limit for the number of shards for a particular miner?

Generally, it is 2-3, but is there a defined upper bound? And what is the process/process in which the network is sharded?

Comment: Ethereum, as I understand it, does not have 'shards'. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @shelvacu The blockchain allocation is [done by sharding](http://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/scalingbitcoin/sharding-the-blockchain/) :)

Comment: I stand corrected! I definitely think this question should stay open.

Comment: @Dawny33 That article you have referenced, is talking about hypothetical Bitcoin sharding, not ethereum sharding. It is quite an interesting set of idea though. Scaling Bitcoin and making mining less wasteful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethereum is not currently sharded. As we work towards a scalability solution, the state will be sharded and validators assigned to shards on a dynamic basis. Note it will be proof of stake, so no mining. The details are still very much being sorted out.